# Post php array insert mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho um formulário JavaScript que envia uma *array*, porem não estou conseguindo recuperar as colunas e seus valores do array para inserir num banco de dados MySQL com PHP.

Exemplo do *array*

```
{"id_deb":"","codbar":"123","id_cat":"20","id_emp":"89","date_at":"2019- 
04-25","valor":"222.22","status":1}
```

Código PHP

```
<?php
include ('../../../../../../server/lib/Connection.class.php');


        //print_R($_POST);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `debitos` (codbar,categoria_id,empresa_id) VALUES('" . $_POST["codbar"] . "', '" . $_POST["id_cat"] . "','" . $_POST["id_emp"] . "')";
        $result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Erro ao inserir dados.'));
}




?>
```

Comment: Olá @Aiolos, seja bem vindo ao SOpt! Adicione o seu código `php` para que o pessoal possa ajudar, sem isso fica difícil auxiliar na solução.

Comment: include ('../../../../../../server/lib/Connection.class.php');

  
  //print_R($_POST);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `debitos` (codbar,categoria_id,empresa_id) VALUES('" . $_POST["codbar"] . "', '" . $_POST["id_cat"] . "','" . $_POST["id_emp"] . "')";
  $result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
 echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} else {
 echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Erro ao inserir dados.'));
}

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta para facilitar a leitura

Comment: Falta o código javascript que envia o array

Comment: Leitura obrigatória: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878) E **nunca** utilize o `@` nas chamadas de funções. Se você não sabe o que está acontecendo, ele só te prejudicará; se você sabe o que está acontecendo saberá evitar.

Comment: Como chega no php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antes de mais nada sugiro que você tome conhecimento dessa informação: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878)

O que você está enviando é um [JSON](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) não um [Array](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranjo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). O `$_POST` é um array associativo de variáveis passados para o script atual via método HTTP POST quando utilizado `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ou `multipart/form-data` como valor do cabeçalho HTTP `Content-Type` na requisição.

Para você recuperar os dados do JSON enviado você pode fazer uso do código abaixo:

```
<?php
require '../../../../../../server/lib/Connection.class.php';

$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));


$sql = "INSERT INTO `debitos` (codbar,categoria_id,empresa_id) VALUES ('" . $dados->codbar . "', '" . $dados->id_cat . "','" . $dados->id_emp . "')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);

if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Erro ao inserir dados.'));
}
```

Vale lembrar que o código acima não é recomendado e o mesmo está sujeito a ataques de [SQL Injection](https://www.hiago.me/2017/04/30/seguranca-sql-injection-os-dados-de-sua-empresa-estao-protegidos/).